# Colocar borde redondeado en Reporting Services

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs, reporting

actualmente estoy usando Report Builder, y quisiera saber la forma para colocar un borde redondeado en las esquina a una tabla o cuadro de texto

Actualmente solo se puede cuadrado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera un borde asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es posible realizar esto? de ser posible como seria

no se si por HTML se podra